# How can I prevent the Windows Terminal app pinned to the taskbar from opening a new tab when the terminal is on the secondary monitor in Windows 11?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, taskbar, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows 11 with two monitors, and I have pinned Windows Terminal to the taskbar. Occasionally, I move the Windows Terminal window to the secondary monitor, but I often forget it's there and end up clicking the Windows Terminal icon on the primary monitor.

*Current behavior:* Clicking the icon causes the Windows Terminal on the secondary monitor to pop up and open a new tab.
*Desired behavior:* Clicking the icon should make the Windows Terminal on the secondary monitor pop up without opening a new tab.

How can I get the desired behavior?

#### Research I've made so far:

I discovered that the Windows Terminal program accepts the command line parameter focus-tab, and executing `wt.exe focus-tab` seems to do exactly what I want. However, I haven't been able to create a shortcut with this command and pin it to the taskbar.

In the Windows Terminal settings, there is an option under *Startup / New instance behavior* with the configuration *"Attach to the most recently used window"*. Changing it to *"Attach to the most recently used window on this desktop"* had no effect.

Comment: I know they killed custom toolbars, but they still allow pinning files to the taskbar. have you tried making e.g. a batch file containing `wt.exe focus-tab` and then pin that file to the taskbar?

Comment: @Yorik, I tried following your suggestion, but I couldn't pin a .bat file to the taskbar. As a test, I renamed the file from .bat to .exe, and then I was finally able to pin it to the taskbar. However, after renaming it back to .bat, the shortcut lost its connection. So, the question now seems to be: 'How can I pin a script to the taskbar? Thanks for the clue!

Comment: Create a shortcut on the desktop for `wt.exe focus-tab`, right-click it and select "Pin to taskbar".

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc! That worked. To pin, had right-click, select "Show more options" and then, the option "Pin to taskbar". The shortcut icon must be changed before pinning. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? Edit: I wrote too early. When I click the newly created shortcut, the Windows Terminal icon appears in the taskbar, so now I have two similar icons in the taskbar: the program icon and the shortcut icon.  :-/

Comment: That's normal - the shortcut launched a program that's not itself, so you have two taskbar icons. Try to start two such to see if `focus-tab` works.

Comment: @harrymc, I did some tests and I can attest the shortcut with focus-tab works. However, I'm not sure this double icon problem is worth the trouble. As Windows 11 taskbar isn't being flexible enough, I think I'll add my case as a feature request in Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a shortcut on the desktop for `wt.exe focus-tab`,
then right-click it and select "Pin to taskbar".

This will create an icon that launches Windows Terminal, which would
be a separate icon on the taskbar that will disappear when Terminal
disappears.